# SFINAE for generic operation on generic type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, enable-if

I have

- a class *Value* which can be construct with different types (*Foo, Bar, int,...*).
- class *Value* should have common operations like <<, ==, <,... proceeded at the underlying type
- I added the operator *<<* outside class definition.

I have to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
};

struct Bar {
};

struct Value {
    template<typename T>
    Value(T) {
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Bar &) {
    return os << "Bar\n";
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Value &value) {

    auto visitor = [&](auto a) -> decltype(os << a) {
        return os << a;
    };

    // Works
    visitor(Bar{});

    // Infinity call of this function with Value.
    visitor(Foo{});

    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Value(1);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example.](https://godbolt.org/g/eCwTbU)

The problem: If the underlying type does not implements the operator<<, the operator<< from *Value* gets called recursive infinity. I want to get a compiler error like *no match for call operator<<(std:ostream&, const Value&)...* to use SFINAE with my visitor pattern (not shown here).

What I need is something like:

```
[&](auto a) -> std::enable_if_t<addressof?(os << a) != addressof?(os << Value{})>::value> {
    return os << a;
};
```

to disable this lambda, if the functions are the same. Is this possible?

Not valuable solutions:

- make Value explicit
- disable construction of Value with Foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying the signature of `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Value &value)` we can check if an attempt to call to `operator<<` for the type that `a` is deduced to in our lambda is well-formed:

```
auto visitor = [&](auto a) -> decltype(
                              static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&, const decltype(a)&)>(&operator<<)
                             (os, a)
                             )
{
    return os << a;
};
```

Works with `Bar`, fails with `Foo` with error message:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to type 'std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&, const Foo&
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/20krv0s31jIW0xu1)

Answer (score 4):

You might add a wrapper to force only one conversion:

```
template <typename T>
struct OneConversion
{
    OneConversion(const T& t) : t(t) {}

    operator const T&() const {return t;}

    const T& t;  
};

template <typename T>
struct isOneConversion : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct isOneConversion<OneConversion<T>> : std::true_type {};

struct Value {
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!isOneConversion<T>::value>* = nullptr>
    Value(T) {}
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Value &value) {

    auto visitor = [&](auto a) -> decltype(os << OneConversion<decltype(a)>(a)) {
        return os << OneConversion<decltype(a)>(a);
    };

    // Works
    visitor(Bar{});

    visitor(Foo{}); // Error as expected.

    return os;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/205327a5557b65a4)

Answer (score 2):

You could replace

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Value &value)
{
    // ...
}
```

with

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, Value>>>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const T &value)
{
    // ...
}
```

You'll still be able to print `Value` objects with it, but without implicit conversions.

Putting it into your code makes it fail at `visitor(Foo{});` with following error, which seems like what you want.

> ```
> ...
> main.cpp:29:12: error: no match for call to '(operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = Value; <template-parameter-1-2> = void; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]::<lambda(auto:1)>) (Foo)'
>  visitor(Foo{});
>  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
> ...
> ```